# How to format Phone string in Ruby with hyphens?

Tags: ruby, string-formatting

I have a problem I can't solve. 
I need to write `phone_format` method that would accept any phone string and output  it in groups of 3 digits with hyphens

`phone_format("555 123 1234") => "555-123-12-34"`

`phone_format("(+1) 888 33x19") => "188-833-19"`

But if it ends with single digit like `999-9`, change it to `99-99`. Ideally it would be a one liner

Comment: I expect your first step will be `str.gsub(/\D/,'')`. For example, `"(+1) 888 33x19".gsub(/\D/,'') #=>  "18883319"`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: He did, in the last line.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_phone) and the [implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/number_helper/number_to_phone_converter.rb) of Ruby on Rails' `number_to_phone` helper method.

Answer (score 3):

```
R = /
    \d{2,3}   # match 2 or 3 digits (greedily)
    (?=       # begin positive lookahead
      \d{2,3} # match 2 or 3 digits 
      |       # or
      \z      # match the end of the string
    )         # end positive lookahead
    /x        # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

Conventionally written

```
R = /\d{2,3}(?=\d{2,3}|\z)/
```

```
def doit(str)
  s = str.gsub(/\D/,'')
  return s if s.size < 4
  s.scan(R).join('-')
end
```

```
doit "555 123 123"
  #=> "555-123-123" 
doit "555 123 1234"
  #=> "555-123-12-34" 
doit "555 123 12345"
  #=> "555-123-123-45" 
doit "(+1) 888 33x19"
  #=> "188-833-19" 
doit "123"
  #=> "123" 
doit "1234"
  #=> "12-34"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really a one-liner: you need to handle the special cases.

```
def cut_by(str, cut)
  str.each_char.each_slice(cut).map(&:join).join('-')
end

def phone_format(str)
  str = str.gsub(/\D/, '')              # cleanup
  if str.size == 4                      # special case 1
    cut_by(str, 2)
  elsif str.size % 3 == 1               # special case 2
    cut_by(str[0..-5], 3) + "-" + cut_by(str[-4..], 2)
  else                                  # normal case
    cut_by(str, 3)
  end
end
```